# Not fetching username and password from textfile

Tags: vb.net, text-files

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = Cashierpath
    System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) ' current
    Dim objReader As StreamReader
    Dim user As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim password As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim check As String


    'Global Variable
    'Dim DirPath7 As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Scrap Data\Cashier Info\Cashiers\")

    For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirPath7, "*.txt")
        Dim fName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
        If user = fName & ".txt" Then
            objReader = New StreamReader(fName)
            check = objReader.ReadToEnd()
            If password = check Then
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome " & user & "!")
                Close()
                My.Forms.Home.Show()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect")

            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When the user enters their "username" and "password" into the textbox's, and clicks on this button, i want this button to check if there is a textfile with the name of the username entered, and if theres a file with that username it must then read it and check if the password matches the string inside the file. if it doesnt match it, it must then display a messagebox saying that "Username or password is incorrect", but nothing happens when i click on this button. No error message appears either.
Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: What is currently not working?

Comment: That im not sure of. If i new that i wouldn't be asking this question. What i will do is compile my project and install it then run it. Maybe that will tell me what my problem is.

Comment: Never, never store passwords in a text file.

Comment: Try running it under the debugger, stepping through it line by line and confirm each variable has the expected value and the correct branches are taken.

Comment: When i started the application and typed in the username and password and clicked the button, nothing happened. No error message or anything. it's suppose to Display a message saying "Welcome 'the users name' !" and then load another form. But it's not doing that

Comment: Where should i stored my passwords?

Comment: String equality is case sensitive and you don't do anything if the file is never found. Perhaps remove your loop and change everything to `dim fname= Path. Combine(DirPath7, string.format("{0}.txt",user)) if File. Exists(fname) Then ... ReadAndCheck... Else MessageBox.Show("file not found no user exists") End if` and substitute the opening and checking if statement in the middle that I've marked ReadAndCheck... Ie starting with objreader=

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, code you put that into code?

Comment: I'm on mobile and fat fingered the enter button before I was done with the above comment. I fixed it but you may need to reload the page

Comment: You also need to make sure you `Dispose` your StreamReader, best all done in a `Using` block. Don't store passwords in text files unless this is a learning exercise! Also when enumerating directories or working with file system  in general, I find it easier to work with DirectoryInfo and FileInfo objects instead. They include properties for name, full name, existence checking a well as moving, renaming, deleting And in the case of files, methods that will return file streams for reading/writing. Granted it all exists in the File static class as well but I find the Info objects easier

Comment: You've already been told once to use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code.  You don't fix bugs just by reading your code.  You watch it in action.  That's why you have an IDE instead of just a text editor.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - i did what you asked and i found my error. Yhis bit of code here  (DirPath7, **"*.txt"**) was my problem. it was searching for for e.g "Name.txt.txt" instead of "Name.txt". So i removed it and now it's displaying the message box and reading the files.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - i'll keep that in mind. Still learning vb.net, it's my first year doing this stuff. Do you have any recommendations on where to save my passwords for the users?

Comment: You'll still get no message when the file is not found if all you fixed was the search string. Store them in a database, but hashed so they aren't the actual password. If you must store in a file, hash the password so it's not easily recovered. But someone could delete the file or alter its contents etc. Also if you still insist on looping through files instead of looking for the one file you need, make sure to break out of the loop once the file is found. Imagine a directory with a million files to read, `Exit For`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - i dislike using loops, they become a lil complicated for me if i don't know what im doing. But thanks for your advice man

Comment: You should still do EnumerateFiles(DirPath7, "*.txt"),your if is backwards it should be `If user&".Txt" = fname` should you keep your current logic. String.Format and string.equals with a comparison mode would probably be better than the concatenation, if only for clarity `if string. Equals(string.format("{0}.txt",user), fname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) then` it'd still be a whole lot easier targeting the single file as opposed to looping the whole structure

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - that sounds a lil to complicated.. I'll just stick with searching for the specifc file simple code method. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim objReader As StreamReader
    Dim user As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim password As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim check As String

    Dim fname = Path.Combine(DirPath7, String.Format("{0}.txt", user))
     If File.Exists(fname) Then
        Using objreader As New StreamReader(fname)
            'objReader = StreamReader(fname)
            check = objreader.ReadToEnd()
            password = check
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " & user & "!")
            Close()
            My.Forms.Home.Show()
        End Using
    Else : MessageBox.Show("file not found, no user exists")
    End If
```

removed the extra **".txt"**

Added **"Do Using"** . . .**"End Using"**

Comment: Do `using objreader as new StreamReader(fname).... End using` then you don't need to call dispose manually and can get rid of the `objreader.close` statement as well, (which btw, `Dispose` implicitly calls)

Answer (score 1):

**What you have there is an awful way to handle user credentials!**

Read this for more information: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Regardless, you're way over-coding it.

Elsewhere in your app (correct use of Combine):

```
' Global Variable
Friend Shared DirPath7 As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Scrap Data", "Cashier Info", "Cashiers")
```

Button Handler:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim User As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
    Dim Pass As String = TextBox2.Text.Trim

    ' Assemble the full expected file path, even if it might be malformed.
    ' The first case check protects against malformed path.
    Dim FilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(DirPath7, String.Format("{0}.txt", User))

    Select Case True
        Case User.Length = 0
            MsgBox("Username is empty", vbExclamation, "Error")
        Case Pass.Length = 0
            MsgBox("Password is empty", vbExclamation, "Error")
        Case Not IO.File.Exists(FilePath)
            MsgBox("No file for User", vbExclamation, "Error")
        Case Not IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath) = Pass
            MsgBox("Wrong Password", vbExclamation, "Error")
        Case Else
            MsgBox(String.Format("Welcome {0}!", User), vbOKOnly, "Success")
            My.Forms.Home.Show()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah just shoot me down. I'm still a newie with vb.net. I haven't fully decided on what to do with the user name and password yet. But thanks for the help thou, it will actually help me with giving out specifc errors in my program.